# Minimize Expected Value of Euclidean Norm

Tags: optimization

Suppose $x = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)^t \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The Probability distribution function of $x$ is $f(x)$. My goal is to minimize the following function,
\begin{equation}
   \underset{a \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\arg\min} \;E\frac{\|x-a\|^2}{\|x-a_p\|},
\end{equation}
where $E$ denotes the expected value and $a_p$ is any given value of $a$. My approach is,

\begin{equation}
  \nabla_{a} E\frac{\|x-a\|^2}{\|x-a_p\|}=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
      -E \frac{x-a}{\|x-a_p\|}=0
\end{equation}
I want to derive an iterative approach to calculate an optimum value of a. But after the last expression, I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an iterative approach.
\begin{align}
E\left(\frac{\|x-a\|^2}{\|x-a_p\|}\right)&= E\left(\frac{\|x-a_p+a_p-a\|^2}{\|x-a_p\|}\right)\\
&=E\left(\|x-a_p\|\right)+2\left\langle a_p-a, E\left(\frac{x-a_p}{\|x-a_p\|}\right)\right\rangle\\
&\hspace{2em}+\|a-a_p\|^2E\big(\|x-a_p\|^{-1}\big)\ .
\end{align}
This is a positive definite quadratic function of $\ a\ $ whose minimum is attained at
$$
a=a_p+\frac{E\left(\frac{x-a_p}{\|x-a_p\|}\right)}{E\big(\|x-a_p\|^{-1}\big)}\ .
$$